# Detect if images are different in real-time

Tags: c++, c, image-processing

I am working on a microscope that streams live images via a built-in video camera to a PC, where further image processing can be performed on the streamed image. Any processing done on the streamed image must be done in "real-time" (minimal frames dropped).

We take the average of a series of static images to counter random noise from the camera to improve the output of some of our image processing routines. 
My question is: how do I know if the image is no longer static - either the sample under inspection has moved or rotated/camera zoom-in or out - so I can reset the image series used for averaging?

I looked through some of the threads, and some ideas that seemed interesting:
Note: using Windows, C++ and Intel IPP. With IPP the image is a byte array (Ipp8u).
1. Hash the images, and compare the hashes (normal hash or perceptual hash?)
2. Use normalized cross correlation (IPP has many variations - which to use?)

Which do you guys think is suitable for my situation (speed)?

Comment: Have you considered using OpenCV?

Answer (score 4):

If you camera doesn't shake, you can, as inVader said, subtract images. Then a sum of absolute values of all pixels of the difference image is sometimes enough to tell if images are the same or different. However, if your noise, lighting level, etc... varies, this will not give you a good enough S/N ratio.
And in noizy conditions normal hashes are even more useless.

The best would be to identify that some features of your object has changed, like it's boundary (if it's regular) or it's mass center (if it's irregular). If you have a boundary position, you'll need to analyze just one line of pixels, perpendicular to that boundary, to tell that boundary has moved. 
Mass center position may be a subject to frequent false-negative responses, but adding a total mass and/or moment of inertia may help.

If the camera shakes, you may have to align images before comparing (depending on comparison method and required accuracy, a single pixel misalignment might be huge), and that's where cross-correlation helps.

And further, you doesn't have to analyze each image. You can skip one, and if the next differs, discard both of them. Here you have twice as much time to analyze an image.
And if you are averaging images, you might just define an optimal amount of images you need and compare just the first and the last image in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

So, simplest thing to try would be to take subsequent images, subtract them from each other and have a look at the difference. Then define some rules including local and global thresholds for the difference in which two images are considered equal. Simple subtraction of bitmap/array data, looking for maxima and calculating the average differnce across the whole thing should be ne problem to do in real time.

Answer (score 0):

If there are varying light conditions or something moving in a predictable way(like a door opening and closing), then something more powerful, albeit slower, like gaussian mixture models for background modeling, might be worth looking into, [click here](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/vsam/Publications/stauffer_cvpr98_track.pdf). It is quite compute intensive, but can be parallelized pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Motion detection algorithms is what is used.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10248/Motion-Detection-Algorithms

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22243/Real-Time-Object-Tracker-in-C

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would take a series of images at a slow fps rate and downsample those images to make them smaller, not too much but enough to speed up the process.

Now you have several options:

You could make a sum of absolute differences of the two images by subtracting them and use a threshold to value if the image has changed.

If you want to speed it up even further I would suggest doing a progressive SAD using a small kernel and moving from the top of the image to the bottom. You can value the complessive amount of differences during the process and eventually stop when you are satisfied.